# Backgroundworker is canceled and locked? How its possible?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, locking

I have strange issue reported by users and once reproduced by me.

I have form with various buttons and each button performs long operation.

When new buttons are clicked old operation will stops and new will be started.

And i noticed strange behaviour:

When i am clicking button sometimes operation doesnot started. 
Operation cannot be started because next code:

```
if (!Worker.IsBusy)
        {
            RunReload();
        }
        else
        {
            isWorkerPendingForNewJob = true;
            Worker.CancelAsync();
        }
```

Cancel is called few times but my worker is always busy!

[image]

When i brake my project execution i noticed that it stops on **lock** section.

Inside this lock i am just creating some objects that are used for all processes.

Brackpoints on image never hits. 
Why backgroundworked is always busy and locked on this line?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a deadlock.  Where all does `PickOrCreateCategory` get called from?

Comment: Only from this background worker run method.

Comment: Make the lockobject at least static and make it private to see if it is used in derived classes that make it deadlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `CancelAsync()`, it just set the flag `CancellationPending` to `true`. You must manually check periodically this flag in your `BackgroundWorker` work function and interrupt it yourself. Are you doing this already?

Here is the [related MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.cancelasync.aspx).

Also, you must ensure that `WorkerSupportsCancellation` is `true` to support `CancelAsync`.

Comment: It cannot be canceled and always busy because of blocked in lock.

Comment: Then it is probably a deadlock. You should try to find out what is locking `syncCategory` (maybe you can put breakpoints everywhere you `lock (syncCategory)`).